# Group of a user when running a setuid executable

Tags: linux, permissions, setuid

If a user, user1 belongs to group1 and also a setuid executable exists that is owned by user1 and group, group2. user1 is not a member of group2.

I am seeing that the executable cannot access files owned by root and group1 (others have no access, (550, root, group1)). Why is this the case? How is the group of a setuid user determined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setuid bit changes *only* the uid and nothing else.

(Also, the kernel *does not know* which groups user1 belongs to, and there's no standard way for getting that information from userspace. For specific uses, like NFS, daemons like rpc.idmapd or various abuse of request_key can handle such requests, but no generic method has been added.)